# PHP MySQL Display Only Unique Values with Multiple Records In Table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am stumped, I don't know how to do get the results on a table using multiple different identifiers and then group the results

Here is my table **ProjectFieldValue** in a nutshell

```
id | project_id | textValue      | dateValue  | fieldKey
================================================================
1  | 1000       | Closed         | NULL       | contract_status
================================================================
2  | 1000       | NULL           | 2019-05-01 | closing_date
================================================================
3  | 1001       | Open           | NULL       | contract_status
================================================================
4  | 1001       | NULL           | 2019-05-22 | closing_date
================================================================
5  | 1002       | Closed         | NULL       | contract_status
================================================================
6  | 1002       | NULL           | 2019-05-11 | closing_date
================================================================
7  | 1003       | Closed         | NULL       | contract_status
================================================================
8  | 1003       | NULL           | 2019-05-24 | closing_date
================================================================
```

I need to run the query to get all records with...

1. The fieldKey of "contact_status" and the textValue of that fieldKey of "Open"
2. The fieldKey of "closing_date" and the dateValue between 2019-05-01
   AND 2019-05-30

Here is what I have tried and I just get a blank query result set

```
select pfv.* 
from ProjectFieldValue pfv
where (pfv.dateValue between '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-30' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'closing_date') 
AND (pfv.textValue = 'Closed' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'contract_status')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to get blank because you are trying to get all records with field key = closing  date and field key = contract status and that is impossible.

You can try to use OR instead of AND.

like

```
select pfv.* 
from ProjectFieldValue pfv
where (pfv.dateValue between '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-30' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'closing_date') 
OR(pfv.textValue = 'Open' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'contract_status')
```

Also I changed the pfv.textValue = 'Close' for pfv.textValue='Open' because of "The fieldKey of "contact_status" and the textValue of that fieldKey of "Open""

Then you are going to get the records that meet

1. The fieldKey of "contact_status" and the textValue of that fieldKey of "Open"
   OR
2. The fieldKey of "closing_date" and the dateValue between 2019-05-01 AND 2019-05-30

If you want to get only 
1. The fieldKey of "contact_status" and the textValue of that fieldKey of "Open"

you can

```
select pfv.* 
from ProjectFieldValue pfv
where pfv.textValue = 'Open' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'contract_status'
```

and to get only the records for

2. The fieldKey of "closing_date" and the dateValue between 2019-05-01 AND 2019-05-30

```
select pfv.* 
from ProjectFieldValue pfv
where (pfv.dateValue between '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-30' AND pfv.fieldKey = 'closing_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split your select in 2 and make a subquery.... check this documentation:

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php